# Get values from a parsed XML Soap Message

Tags: php, xml, wcf, soap

I'm trying to consume a C# WCF Webservice with PHP, and I'm currently facing a really big problem.

First, let me show you what one of the the WCF Webservice responses looks like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <s:envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <s:header>
         <activityid xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/09/ServiceModel/Diagnostics" correlationid="6b8187a6-79a9-4bc4-a195-7c3b66547408">b340ad42-7be9-466c-a9f1-4048d35b7cb5</activityid>
      </s:header>
      <s:body>
     <getalljobsresponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
        <getalljobsresult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Transcode.Webservice.Messages" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
           <a:jobinfo>
              <a:associatedfilesize>34551192</a:associatedfilesize>
              <a:associateduserid>10</a:associateduserid>
              <a:jobcompletiondate>2016-06-09T10:37:42.2568136</a:jobcompletiondate>
              <a:jobid>29</a:jobid>
              <a:jobsubmissiondate>2016-06-09T10:37:27.8522463</a:jobsubmissiondate>
              <a:remotefilepath>ftp://localhost/transcode_uploads/Luc/LinkinPark-DontStay.au</a:remotefilepath>
              <a:taskprice>0.05</a:taskprice>
              <a:taskstate>2</a:taskstate>
           </a:jobinfo>
           <a:jobinfo>
              <a:associatedfilesize>34551192</a:associatedfilesize>
              <a:associateduserid>10</a:associateduserid>
              <a:jobcompletiondate>2016-06-09T11:46:07.7590635</a:jobcompletiondate>
              <a:jobid>1029</a:jobid>
              <a:jobsubmissiondate>2016-06-09T11:45:55.8115507</a:jobsubmissiondate>
              <a:remotefilepath>ftp://localhost/transcode_uploads/Luc/LinkinPark-DontStay.au</a:remotefilepath>
              <a:taskprice>0.05</a:taskprice>
              <a:taskstate>2</a:taskstate>
           </a:jobinfo>
        </getalljobsresult>
     </getalljobsresponse>
  </s:body>
</s:envelope>
```

I'm trying everything to get a jobinfo element with all its attributes, but it doesn't seem to work well ...

I tried the following line of code :

```
$xml->getElementsByTagName('associatedfilesize')->item(0)->nodeValue
```

And it works on a single attribute, as for jobid or anything else !

The problem is, I would like to get a jobInfo objet in its entirety, by using something like :

```
$xml->getElementsByTagName('jobInfo')
```

Could you please help me guys, I have very little time left to finish my work and I'm stuck on that issue for too long...

Comment: What do you get when you do: $xml->getElementsByTagName('jobInfo'); ? You must be getting an array.

Comment: If I print it this way :
print_r($dom->getElementsByTagName('jobinfo'));
We have this result : DOMNodeList Object ( [length] => 0 )

If I do it this way : 
var_dump($dom->getElementsByTagName('jobinfo'));
We have this result:
object(DOMNodeList)[5]

Comment: Your comment reflects that its returning an object. You just need to cast it to array and then you can iterate over the array.

Comment: Thx for you answers.
If I try to "cast" it into an array like that :

 $jobs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('jobinfo');

 $array = array();
 foreach($jobs as $element){
     $array[] = $element;
 }
 var_dump($array);

I get as a result :

array (size=0)
  empty